# Seeking "Flexible" Probability Distribution with Compact Support?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request, compactness, mathematical-modeling

I am looking for a probability distribution that

1. is *continuous* with *compact* support $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$
2. is "flexible" in that its *mean*, *variance*, and *skew* can be tractably manipulated (e.g. by changing parameters).

To illustrate what I mean, here are some examples of distributions that partially accomplish  the above:

- the [raised cosine distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raised_cosine_distribution) allows for flexible manipulation of its variance.
- the [wrapped normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_normal_distribution) and [von Mises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_distribution) distributions allow one to flexibly manipulate the mean and variance.

Does anyone know of a *continuous* distribution with *compact support* whose *mean*, *variance*, **and *skew*** can be systematically manipulated?

Apologies for the imprecise question. Please let me know if you would like me to clarify anything.

Answer (score 2):

The [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Skewness) is commonly used as a "swiss army knife" of probability distributions with finite support. If the support is fixed, you only have two parameters, so your mean, variance, and skew may not be independently selectable .